# What are some ways a planet with a diameter 12 times that of Earth could have a mass barely any larger than Earth’s?

Tags: science-based, planets

In my stories, there exists an inhabitable, Earth-like, terrestrial planet called Ozarvis 32. Ozarvis 32 has a diameter of 95,110 miles, which I’ve calculated as being about 12 times the diameter of Earth, yet has a mass only of less than 1.05 times that of Earth.

For the record, I’ve already decided on 2 ways Ozarvis could have such a low mass for its size:

1. Ozarvis’s oceans are about 2.5 times deeper than Earth’s.
2. Ozarvis’s lithosphere has a system of massive caves inside of it. Each of these caves and tunnels are significantly larger than any cave on Earth: for reference, I’ll say most of the tunnels in these caves are big enough for a boulder with a diameter of about 13.5 miles to be able to fit (though it would certainly fill most of the space), and lead into caverns that are significantly larger.

However, from what I can tell, that wouldn’t be enough to make Ozarvis 32’s mass less than 1.05 times greater than Earth’s. If I’m wrong, let me know, but the question remains: what are some other ways for a planet about 12 times larger than Earth to have a mass that’s less than 1.05 times greater than Earth’s?

Comment: The problem here isn't material (well, it is that too) but surface gravity. A planet with 12 times the radius of Earth but with the same mass would have a surface gravity of 1/144 G, which is roughly equivalent to that of Saturn's moon Mimas. Even worse, that's without accounting for rotation: if its day is shorter than 2.5 Earth days, its gravity would be too weak to stop objects on its equator from flying off into space.

Comment: @biziclop Yeah, I’m starting to realize my understanding of how a planet’s gravity works is way, way off.

Comment: The whole point of why I originally listed Ozarvis 32 as having a diameter 12 times Earth’s and a mass so close to Earth’s was because I thought that’d make it habitable. I just didn’t understand how gravity works.

Comment: Yes, to have the same surface gravity (not counting rotation), you need it to be 144 times as heavy as Earth.  Which actually makes the material question slightly less tricky, although we're still talking about a planet with a density that is 1/12th of Earth's, way lighter than water. For comparison, the "lightest" planet in our solar system is Saturn, with a density about 1/8th of Earths. And it's a gas giant.

Comment: The larger a planet is, the less dense it has to be to have substantial surface gravity, because the volume increases by the cube of the radius while surface gravity decreases by the square.  But building a terrestrial planet 144 times the mass of Earth seems like a non-starter as well, at least for anything natural.

Comment: Also, the minimum viable core mass for a gas giant is ~10 Earth masses.  If your planet masses 144 Earth masses, it's going to want very much to be a gas giant.

Comment: Do you really want a jupiter sized "earth like" planet? If you could settle for 12 times the surface area and 1g surface gravity, things would get much more managable..

Answer (score 14):

With a diameter 12 times that of Earth, the volume will be $12^3$ times that of Earth.

To have the same mass, you would need the average density to be $1/12^3$ that of Earth, which would not qualify as a planet, but rather a gas cloud.

Even Saturn, which is less dense than water, is way denser than the 0.002 kg/dm3 I estimate with what I said above.

Comment: It works out to about 4 times the density of air at sea level...

Answer (score 5):

## Magical Metamaterials (ie. Magrathea)

The way your planet can achieve this is by being built.

You cannot have a natural cave thirteen miles in diameter for the same reason that you couldn't build a granite dome thirteen miles in diameter; without supports, it would simply collapse under its own weight (or, in the lithosphere, by the pressure of the quadrillions of tonnes of mass around it).

A planet 12 times Earth's radius but of equal mass would, by necessity, have to be $\frac{1}{12}^3 = 0.0005787$ its density.  This would be circa 0.003188 $g/cm^3$.  By comparison, the density of nitrogen at STP is 0.0012506 $g/cm^3$.  So the *vast majority* of your postulated planet would have to be a light gas or vacuum.

So let's go Larry Niven on this thing.  Your planet's crust, under a trivially thin layer of granite to fake being a natural planet, is made of [scrith](https://www.trevorwrites.com/blog/2019/8/5/impossible-technologies-1-ringworlds).  The interior is actually hollow.  If the interior is a vacuum, then even with the enormous volume of granite, water, etc. to make the outside look "real", you stay within your mass budget.  (Because the surface area is 144 times that of Earth, you need a *lot* of surface material.)

How did this come about?  Someone ordered it made by a [company that specializes in building planets to order](https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/Magrathea).

I should point out that at twelve times Earth's radius but stuck at Earth's mass, [your surface gravity is going to be *tiny*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=surface+gravity+calculator), about 0.007 G.  This would make its "inhabitable" status kind of doubtful.

Comment: Ok. Your last point shows how wrong my understanding of the relation between the diameter, gravity and mass of a planet is. I thought that Ozarvis 32 having a mass nearly identical to Earth’s would make it’s gravity inhabitable, not uninhabitable.

Comment: @GodzillaLouise - the equation for surface gravity is $a=\frac{GM}{R^2}$.  You're holding M constant, and multiplying R by 12.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out, such a planet would have to be artificial and hollow to have a diameter 12 times that of Earth and a mass less than 1.05 that of Earth, and it would have to be made of a material many, many time stronger than any known material.

Now consider the planet's gravity.

Part One: Surface Gravity.

According to this surface gravity calculator:

https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/acceleration-due-to-gravity

The acceleration of surface gravity of a planet with 1.05 times the mass of earth and 12 times the radius of Earth would be 0.0716 meters per second per second, or 0.007302 *g*, 0.007302 of the gravitational acceleration of Earth.

Humans who spend more than a few months in the zero gravity in Earth orbit suffer from declining physical health.  And it is quite likely that humans on a planet with a surface gravity of only 0.007302 *g* might be no better off health wise than humans in zero gravity, making that planet a deathtrap for humans who settle there.

Thus the human settlers there would have to build a lot of giant centrifuges and spend an as yet undetermined proportion of their time in those centrifuges under a higher but as yet undetermined simulated gravity to maintain their health.

It is quite possible that humans on Earth might do the same in the future to strengthen their bodies and improve their health, in which case it would be no big deal for the human settlers on the planet to do the same.

In other circumstances, having to spend a lot of time in centrifuges might be very annoying for human colonists.

Hypothetical Intelligent aquatic beings from Earth, such as hypothetical intelligent cetaceans or cephalopods, might find the oceans on your world suitable, and might or might not not notice the difference in gravity.

Lifeforms which evolved on the planet and in its low gravity would probably be perfectly adjusted to its gravity.

Part Two: Escape Velocity.

There is another aspect of a planet's gravity which is very important to its habitability.  Its escape velocity.

According to this escape velocity calculator:

https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/escape-velocity

A planet with only 1.05 times the mass of Earth and 12 times the radius of Earth  (and thus 1,728 times the volume of Earth) would have an escape velocity of 3.309 kilometers per second, which is about 0.2958161 of Earth's escape velocity of 11.186 kilometers per second.

So your hypothetical planet would have 0.007302 of the gravitational acceleration of Earth and also about 0.2958161 of Earth's escape velocity.  0.2958161 divided by 0.007302 is 40.51.   The ratio of the planet's escape velocity to that of Earth is about 40.51 times as high as the ratio of its surface gravity to that of Earth.

A science fiction writer cannot assume that the escape velocity and the surface gravity of a planet they are designing with both have the same ratio to Earth's values of those factors.  Instead they must calculate the surface gravity and the escape velocity separately using their separate formulas (or separate online calculators).

And what is the importance of your world's escape velocity?

Part Three: Atmospheric Retention.

Earth's biosphere includes many regions where lifeforms exist but where an unprepared human teleported to would swiftly die.  For example, kilometers or miles high in the atmosphere or under the surface of the oceans or underground in rock.

So scientists discussing the hypothetical habitability of other worlds usually discuss habitability for liquid water using lifeforms in general and not for large multi celled oxygen breathing lifeforms like humans in particular.  Thus scientists may consider a real or hypothetical planet to possibly be habitable even if any lifeforms which science fiction writers consider to make an environment interesting for story telling would swiftly die there.

I know of one scientific study of habitability specifically for humans (and which largely applies to all multi celled land dwelling oxygen using plants and animals that a science fiction writer would find interesting).

To be continued:

*Habitable Planets for Man*, Stephen H. Dole, 1964.

https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/commercial_books/2007/RAND_CB179-1.pdf

The ability of a planet to retain atmosphere for geological eras of time depends on the escape velocity of the world and the velocities of the gases in the escape layers of the atmosphere, the exosphere.

On page 34 Dole says that there are theories to calculate the retention of atmosphere which depend on detailed knowledge of the structure and composition of a specific atmosphere.  And there is a rough rule of thumb to estimate how long a planet can retain a specific gas in its atmosphere.  It uses the ratio of the world's escape velocity divided by the root-mean-square of the velocity of that gas at the temperature in the exosphere where gases are lost from.

Dole gives a formula for calculating the time it will take for an atmosphere gas to drop to 1/*e*, or 0.368, of its original value.

Table 5 on page 35 gives examples of the ratio of the escape velocity divided y the root-mean-square velocity of that gas and gives the times it will take that gas to drop to 0.368 of its original value.

If the ratio is as low as one or two, the gas will drop to 0.368 of its original value instantly.  If the ratio is three, it will take a few weeks to drop that much.  If the ratio is four, it will take a few thousand years to drop that much. If the ratio is five, it will take about a hundred million years to drop that much.  If the ratio is six, it will take approximately infinite time to drop that much.

So an increase in the ratio from to six is enough to change the atmospheric retention time from zero to infinite.   The escape velocity of a planet is very important in determining how long it can retain a gas in it's atmosphere.  If the world losses a gas slowly enough, that gas might be replaced at an equal rate by some process.

There are other processes which cause worlds to lose atmosphere.  The solar or stellar wind can knock gas particles out of the upper atmosphere and into interplanetary space, which is called sputtering.

Earth's magnetic field pulls charged particles in the solar wind into the Van Allen radiation belts and keeps them from most of Earth's atmosphere, reducing the rate of atmospheric loss by sputtering.

So one might suspect that the planet Venus shouldn't have much atmosphere left by now, after 4.6 billion years.

Venus has an escape velocity of 10.36 kilometers per second, 0.926 that of Earth.

Venus is much closer to the Sun than Earth, about 0.723 as far, and thus should receive about 2.6525 times a such radiation from the Sun as Earth does, thus making its atmospheric gases much hotter and faster moving.

Because Venus is about 0.723 as far from the Sun as Earth, the solar wind should be about 2.625 times as strong at the orbit of Venus than at the orbit of Earth.

And Venus has no magnetic field to deflect charged particles and protect the atmosphere of Venus.

> The atmosphere of Venus is primarily of supercritical carbon dioxide and is much denser and hotter than that of Earth. The temperature at the surface is 740 K (467 °C, 872 °F), and the pressure is 93 bar (1,350 psi), roughly the pressure found 900 m (3,000 ft) underwater on Earth.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Venus#cite_note-Barabash2007-48

So clearly the solar wind of the Sun is not strong enough to rapidly erode the atmosphere a planet with mass similar to Earth orbiting in the habitable zone of the Sun.  However, some stars have stellar winds many times as intense as that of the Sun, which may rapidly erode the atmospheres of any  planets in their habitable zones.

Part Four: The Minimum Escape Velocity.

On page 54 Dole discussed the minimum possible mass of a human habitable planet with an oxygen rich atmosphere.

Earth has an average surface temperature of about 59 degrees F or 15 degrees C or 288 degrees K.  On page 54 Dole says that the temperatures in Earth's exosphere, the layer that gases escape into space from, is about 1000 to 2000 K, (which is about 3.47222 to 6.94444 times the surface temperature of Earth.  The exosphere temperature being so much higher than the surface temperature means that the gases are travelling much faster up there and can escape easier.

On page 54 Dole says that if a world can have an Earth like surface temperature while having a maximum exosphere temperature of only 1000 K, it could retain atomic oxygen for about 100 million years if it had an escape velocity of only 6.25 kilometers per second (0.5587 the escape velocity of Earth), which is five times the 1.25 kilometers per second that is the root-men-square velocity of atomic oxygen at a temperature of 1000 degrees K.

Dole believed that the most probable design for a world with an escape velocity of 6.25 kilometers per second would be with a mass of 0.195 Earth mass, a radius of 0.63 Earth radius (and thus 4,013.7 kilometers), and a surface gravity of 0.49 *g*.

Dole believed that such a small world would not be able to form a dense, oxygen rich, atmosphere and spent the next few pages trying to estimate the minimum mas for a planet that could form an oxygen rich atmosphere.

But a minimum escape velocity of 6.25 kilometers per second, 1.888 times the calculated escape velocity of 3.309 kilometers per second of your world, would seem to prove that your world could not possibly retain an oxygen rich and dense atmosphere.

Part Five: What About Titan?

What about Titan. the largest moon of Saturn?

To be continued.

Titan has a surface gravity of about 0.138 *g*  and an escape velocity of 2.641 kilometers per second (0.236 earth's).  That is less than the calculated escape velocity of your world at 3.309 kilometers per second.

Titan has a dense atmosphere which is mainly nitrogen.

> Observations from the Voyager space probes have shown that Titan's atmosphere is denser than Earth's, with a surface pressure about 1.45 atm. It is also about 1.19 times as massive as Earth's overall,[44] or about 7.3 times more massive on a per surface area basis.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(moon)#Atmosphere

Titan is very cold, with a surface temperature of about 94 K, or -179 C, or

- 290 F.  And the exosphere temperatures should also be much lower than on Earth, thus enabling Titan to retain its atmosphere.

The exosphere temperatures of worlds are not caused by all the radiation which They receive, but only by the ultraviolet radiation.  And of course the lower the surface temperature of a star is, the less ultraviolet radiation it will emit.

So a world with an escape velocity of 3.309 or 2.641 kilometers per second could have an Earthlike surface temperature and a dense oxygen rich atmosphere if it orbited a star much cooler than the Sun, and didn't get much ultraviolet radiation from its star, but did get about as much visible and infrared radiation as Earth gets.

Mars orbits the Sun abut 1.523 times as distant as Earth does, and so receives about 0.431 times as much radiation, including ultraviolet, as Earth does.  It has an escape velocity of 5.027 kilometers per second, 1.519 times that of your world and 1.9 times that of Titan.  But it has an atmosphere only about 1 percent as dense as Earth's.

Clearly receiving 0.431 times as much ultraviolet radiation as Earth gets is still too much for Mars to have a cool enough exosphere to retain most gases for geological eras.

Saturn, and thus Titan, orbits the Sun at 9.5826 times the distance of Earth's orbit. So Titan receives 0.0108 times as much ultraviolet radiation from the Sun as Earth does, and thus its exosphere is cold enough to retain a dense atmosphere for geological eras.

So for your world to be warm enough for life as we know it it should receive about as much visible and infrared light as Earth gets from the Sun, but less than 0.431 times as much ultraviolet light, possibly as low as 0.0108 times as much ultraviolet.

Part Six: Tidally Locked?

If your world has to orbit a vey low mass and dim star to avoid ultraviolet radiation, the habitable zone of that star might be so close that any planets in e habitable zone would be tidally locked to the star.

It has long been feared that a tidally locked planet would have all its atmosphere and water freeze solid on the dark side, becoming airless and lifeless.

But if a world large enough to be habitable was a giant moon that orbited around a giant planet, it would become tidally locked to the planet instead of the star, and so would have cycles of light and dark, heat and cold, and would preserve its atmosphere and water.

Thus the hypothetical advanced civilization which built your artificial world would have found an Earth mass moon moon of a giant planet, took it apart, converted is materials into hypothetical super strong materials, and built a giant hollow shell in orbit around the giant planet.

I note that such a giant hollow shell, with a radius of 12 Earth radii, and thus about 76,452 kilometers, would have a larger radius than Jupiter, and so would probably be at least as large - though with only a tiny fraction of the mass - as the planet it orbited.

And some recent studies indicate that a tidally locked planet with a decent atmosphere would have the atmosphere and water distribute heat from the lighted side to the dark say and maintain relatively consistent temperatures on both sides of the planet.

Part Seven: A Rogue Planet?

If the problems of having your constructed planet orbit a dim red dwarf star are too great, it might be a rogue planet in interstellar space lightyears form the nearest star.  The civilization which built it would have found an Earth mass rogue planet in interstellar space, took it apart, converted its mass into hypothetical high strength materials, and built a vast hollow shell out of those materials.

Such a planet would have no problem with too much ultraviolet light lightyears from the nearest star. Instead it would have a problem with not enough visible and infrared light light years from the nearest star.  It would be extremely cold, unless the civilization which built it built in many giant heating units to warm it up to liquid water temperatures.

They would also have to build a giant satellite in orbit around the constructed world which had gigantic lamps to light the world with visible light.

Part eight: Magnets?

Of course the super strong materials used to build such a shell are unknown  to present day materials science and are considered to be extremely unlikely.

So possibly the shell of the world could be kept from collapsing under its gravity by giant electromagnets.  Like magnetic charges repeal each other.  So giant electromagnets with the same charge could keep the shell from collapsing without using improbable super strong materials.

One problem with that would be the magnets and their power sources might produce a lot of waste heat, enough to make the world uninhabitable.

Another problem reminds me of the old space opera series of Interstellar Patrol stories by Edmund "World Wrecker" Hamilton from 1928 to 1930. Most of the enemy planets in those stories had master controls for powerful machinery, which would destroy those planets if set the wrong way.  And in some of of those stories a hero of the Interstellar Patrol saved the day by throwing the switch which destroyed the enemy world.

And if power to the electromagnets is cut off, the world would collapse under its gravity to eventually form a much smaller and more normal type of planet.

And some writers might think that if using a highly improbably strong construction material was good enough for Larry Niven in *Ringworld* It is good enough for them.

And those are some factors to consider in deciding whether to use a world which has 1.05 times he mass of earth and 12 times the radius of Earth in a story.

Comment: An artificially constructed Hollow Earth is the only plausible answer here, given the extreme low density.

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming you want Earth-like gravity rather than Earthlike mass:**

Surface gravity of a celestial body is directly proportional to an object's mass and inversely proporional to the square of its radius. With Earth gravity and 12 times Earth radius, the density must be 1/12 Earth's, or roughly 0.5 g per cubic cm, half that of water.

The only mineral or solid with that low a density is liquid acetylene  (0.38 g per cubic cm), which is highly unstable at high pressure. Probably not the way to go...
Alternatively, your planet could consist mainly of a porous solid that traps air. Of special interest are [aerogels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerogel), which are basically crystals or gels with all the trapped water eliminated and replaced by air. Some aerogels are only a little heavier than the air trapped in them; as low as 0.0019 g per cubic cm at 1 atmosphere. Aerogels are also very strong; a 2.5 kg brick can be supported by a piece of aerogel with a mass of 2 g. Aerogels can also resist high pressure; I can find [one instance](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/321649043_Aerogel_IC3120_Under_High_Pressure_Exerted_Mechanically_and_by_Nitrogen) where an aerogel was subjected to a pressure of 450 MPa, four times the pressure at the bottom of the Mariana Trench. I can only conjecture how an aerogel would react at the far more extreme pressure at the core of a planet, but its density would increase as the density of the air inside increases with pressure, and this would create an equilibrium with the outside pressure. [Nitrogen becomes a metallic fluid](https://www.sci.news/physics/metallic-nitrogen-06183.html) at the extreme pressure and temperature at the Earth's core. I cannot, however, find any data about the density of this liquid.

Still, I imagine that a planet mainly consisting of air-filled aerogel with a metallic core could hold up structurally. I doubt that there is any way such a planet could form naturally, so there would have to be some kind of megastructure engineering involved.

Comment: If the planet has 12 times earth diameter but the same surface gravity, it will have 12^3 times the volume but needs 12^2 the mass, so you need a density of 1/12 of earth density. That comes to around 0.5g/cm^3 not 2g/cm^3 so actually half the density of water.

Comment: @quarague: My bad - I will correct. :-)